# Automatic reply with function Getsignature

Tags: vba, outlook, automation

I'm not fan of VBA, but I'm trying to build a simple VBA code, to set-up auto-reply.

I'm 100% sure, i have a mistakte in the code, but i can't find it:

```
Option Explicit


Sub AutoReply(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim olOutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Strsignature As String
Dim Spath As String

Strsignature = GetSignature(Spath)
Spath = "my_path" '->validpath

With olItem
    Set olOutMail = olItem.Reply
    With olOutMail
        .Subject = "my_subject"
        .HTMLBody = "my_text" & Strsignature
        .Display        'send
        End With
    Set olOutMail = Nothing
End With
End Sub
```

**Function:**

```
Function GetSignature(fPath As String) As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim TSet As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TSet = fso.GetFile(fPath).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
GetSignature = TSet.ReadAll
TSet.Close
End Function
```

**Testing:**

```
Sub Test()
Dim olMsg As MailItem
On Error Resume Next
Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
AutoReply olMsg
End Sub
```

If i run the "Testing" code, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please, move `Spath = "my_path"` above the line `Strsignature = GetSignature(Spath)`.

Otherwise, the function is called with an empty string like parameter. `GetSignature` function must firstly check if the string exists.

The `AutoReply` code can also check it:

```
If Strsignature = "" Then Stop 'or send a message
```

2. adapt `htmlBody` to be a HTML string:

```
.htmlBody = "<H3><B>My_text</B></H3>" & "<br>" & Strsignature
```

You must not use `On error Resume Next` at the beginning of your code. Why is it necessary, except not letting you seeing where the problem is?

Comment: I didn't recognized `On error Resume Next`. I deleted it, and my "valid"path was not valid :) Thank you!

Comment: As a general note, you cannot concatenate two HTML strings and expect a valid HTML back. .The two must be merged.